# AngularJs - Show a popup displaying values from scope

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to show a pop up with values from docDetails on hover of on of the item.
looking at something like

```
<div ng-repeat="row in docDetails">
            <div ng-mouseover="hoverIn()" ng-mouseleave="hoverOut()" class="col-sm-2">
                {{row.DocumentTypeName}}

<span class="??" style="white-space: normal;" ng-show="hoverEdit">
                    {{row.DocumentUploadedBy}}
                </span>
```

`hoverEdit` set to `true/false` in `hoverIn()` and `hoverOut()` method.

I am looking at two things
On hover , i want to show a mouse hand, and display a small pop up with   content `{{row.DocumentUploadedBy}}`

Anything from bootstrap i can readily use? Open to all suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: Please share fiddle or plunker

Comment: Sorry i  dont have a working version, I give an idea i posted this sample. docDetails obj array contains DocumentTypeName and DocumentUploadedBy

Comment: Questions asking for recommendations of third party tools or libraries are off topic for this site, due to the amount of spam they generate.

Answer (score -2):

Here is something you can try [Plunker][1]
Please use the link mentioned below

http://plnkr.co/edit/J050zPX5rhLmS2HVBAGy `Plunker`

or in other terms use something like this mentioned below

script-

var app = angular.module("app",[]);

app.controller('main',["$scope",function($scope){

```
$scope.docDetails = [
    {DocumentTypeName:"Type-1",DocumentUploadedBy:"User-1",ShowInfo:false},
    {DocumentTypeName:"Type-2",DocumentUploadedBy:"User-2",ShowInfo:false},
    {DocumentTypeName:"Type-3",DocumentUploadedBy:"User-3",ShowInfo:false},
    {DocumentTypeName:"Type-4",DocumentUploadedBy:"User-4",ShowInfo:false}
];
```

}]);

and the HTML as

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.17" data-semver="1.3.17" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.17/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body >
    <div ng-controller="main">
    <div style="border:1px solid black; height:200px;">
      {{hoverEdit}}
      <div ng-repeat="row in docDetails">
            <div style="border:1px solid red; width:200px; height:20px;" ng-mouseover="row.ShowInfo=true" ng-model="hoverEdit" ng-mouseleave="row.ShowInfo=false"> 
            {{row.DocumentTypeName}}
            <span style="white-space: normal;" ng-show="row.ShowInfo" > {{row.DocumentUploadedBy}} </span> </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Link only answers aren't considered helpful, as the links themselves can change.  And this is definitely a link only answer, even though the link is in comments rather than the answer body.  It's best if you post the relevant parts of the link in the answer.

Comment: just moving the link from the comments to the body doesn't improve the quality of the answer; it's still a link only answer, since we can't read the answer and know anything about the proposed solution without clicking the link.

Comment: @Claies  - Is it fine now in the ans itself